ASP.NET Core: why is returning a Razor view + its model via a controller not the same of navigating to that Razor page?
I noticed that if you try to access the ViewData dictionary in a Razor view returned via a controller (return View("<RazorPageName>", new RazorPageNameModel())), it is null. This means that navigating to a Razor page and having its view returned via a controller is not the same.
I'm missing the point of having two different behaviors on top of the same set of objects/classes. I'd appreciate it if someone could clarify this context a bit more.
== UPDATE ==
Below is an example of returning the Razor page MyRazorPage via an MVC controller. As said, doing this achieves a different result than navigating directly via your browser to the MyRazorPage Razor page.
[Route("Test")]
public class TestController : Controller
{
    [Route("GetMeThatRazorView")]
    public IActionResult GetMyView()
    {
        return View("MyRazorPage", new MyRazorPageModel());
    }
}


Do you mean ViewData dictionary?

ahahaha, thank you for catching my typo

if I understood correctly, you have razor page and you are trying to use its view in controller?

Added further details to my question. Is my question really that unclear?

I still don't understand your question you return a razor page inside the MVC controller ?

that's unusual use case. you shouldn't mix razor pages and controllers. guess, you could copy razor page content to Razor View

mixing controllers and razor pages is common is non overly simple scenarios - the advantage of controllers is that they can return whatever content/view they want as if it was rendered by the same page without having to resort to a redirect

Creating a new PageModel doesn't return anything... only after methods are called (onGet, onGetAsync, onPost, onPostAsync) is a PageResult returned: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.razorpages.pageresult?view=aspnetcore-8.0

new PageModel() return exactly what is says, a new PageModel instance :) A PageResult is something different. Where is it that I've said that a PageModel and a PageResult are the same thing?

well you're going to need some kind of data to pass to the view... ViewData from the PageResult maybe?  But the PageModel's methods that ultimately render the page need to be called first?  And it'll end up rendering the whole she-bang I think, so... well it's an odd thing to do.

you might try something like: return View("MyRazorPage", new MyRazorPageModel().onGet().ViewData);  ?  (onGet() should return an IActionResult which is a PageResult... ? but I think it also executes the action...)

This is because of the different page life for the MVC and the razor page.
If you add the @page inside the view, it will be render as the razor page life cycle, the razor page's life cycle contains its own viewdata render , so MVC life cycle's view data will not go to that.
Simply remove the @page inside your razor page view, you will find  the viewdata could work well.
The viewdata is render during the page render life cycle.
Besides, the razor page and MVC is different things, I don't suggest you return razor page view inside the MVC controller. If you need the functionality of ViewData within a Razor Page context, you must set it within the Razor Page's PageModel.
